# Do I use a properties file or just flat file to store a list of strings in JSP?

Tags: jsp, properties, whitelist, blacklist

I have a config.properties file which my JSP page uses to get configurations from. I need to create a whitelist, which just contains strings. Since property files are like key value pairs do I need to have another whitelist.txt or something? or can I specify an array of items in properties file itself?

Comment: Why is a JSP page getting configurations from a file at all? How long is the list? You could use CSV if it's short. If it's really long I'd keep it a separate file. You could have a property that names the file. And read it in a servlet, not a JSP.

Comment: Hmm you are right.. But I just need to give out a JSP file so trying to keep it small. Probably external file to store the whitelist is the deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in this cases I use a simple .txt file and read it with commons-io or guava:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/wordlist.txt"); //class-path relative
List<String> words = CharStreams.readLines(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: The following worked.                                      InputStream whitestream = application.getResourceAsStream("/whitelist.txt");
 BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whitestream));
 String line = "";
 while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(line);
 }
 input.close();